# Show a number range as multiples of 1s, 10s, 100s, 1,000s and 10,000s in Perl

Tags: perl, numbers, range

I have a range of 8-digit numbers. I need to feed the range to a system that can only accept:

- an 8-digit number `12345678`
- multiple of 10's `1234567*`
- multiple of 100's `123456*`
- multiple of 1,000's `12345*`
- multiple of 10,000's `1234*`

so I need to expand a given range to fit the above. For example:

```
99888888 => [99888888]

12008000..12008009 => [1200800*]

11110000..11119999 => [1111*]

86008002..86008007 => [86008002, 86008003, 86008004, 86008005, 86008006, 86008007]

22000168..22000340 => [22000168, 22000169, 2200017*, 2200018*, 2200019*, 220002*, 2200030*, 2200031*, 2200032*, 2200033*, 22000340]

44001685..44001714 => [44001685, 44001686, 44001687, 44001688, 44001689, 4400169*, 4400170*, 44001710, 44001711, 44001712, 44001713, 44001714]
```

I wrote a Perl script that works, but I feel it could be more compact and elegant. Perhaps use one sub with recursion instead of 2.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'signatures';
use Number::Range;
use Data::Dumper;

my $range = Number::Range->new("86008002..86008007,12008000..12008009,44001685..44001714,11110000..11119999,22000168..22000340,99888888");

sub reduce($s, $e) {
    if ($s=~/^0+$/ && $e=~/^9+$/) {
        return ("*");
    }
    elsif ($s=~/^\d$/ && $e=~/^\d$/) {
        return ($s .. $e);
    }
    else {
        my ($s0,$s1) = $s =~ /^(\d)(\d+)$/; # save the first digit, and the remaining ones
        my $slast = $s1 =~ s/\d/9/gr; # replace the remaining digits with 9's
        my $sfull = $s0.$slast;
        my @s = map { $s0 . $_ } reduce($s1, $slast);

        my ($e0,$e1) = $e =~ /^(\d)(\d+)$/; # save the first digit, and the remaining ones        
        my $efirst = $e1 =~ s/\d/0/gr; # replace the remaining digits with 0's
        my $efull = $e0.$efirst;
        my @e = ();
        @e = map { $e0 . $_ } reduce($efirst, $e1) unless $s0==$e0 && $s1==$efirst && $slast==$e1; # avoid duplicates
        
        #say STDERR "#s#-> $s - '$sfull' [$s0 . $slast] => @s";
        my @m = ();
        if ($efull - $sfull > 1) { # middle range
            @m = reduce($sfull+1, $efull-1);        
            #say STDERR "#m#-> '".($sfull+1)."' - '".($efull-1)."' => @m";
        }
        #say STDERR "#e#-> '$efull' - $e [$e0 . $efirst] => @e";

        return (@s, @m, @e);
    }
}

sub expand($r) {
    if (scalar @$r > 1) {
        my $start = $r->[0];
        my $end   = $r->[1];
        say STDOUT "Range: $start..$end";
        my $mult = 10000;
        my ($s0, $e0);
        while ($mult > 0) {
            my $s = int($start/$mult);
            my $e = int($end/$mult);

            last if $s != $e;
            ($s0,$e0) = ($s,$e);
            $mult /= 10;
        }
        die unless $s0 == $e0;
        
        my $s1 = $start =~ s/^$s0//r;
        my $e1 = $end   =~ s/^$e0//r;

        my @array = map { $s0 . $_ } reduce($s1,$e1);
        say STDOUT "Final= ${s0}[$s1-$e1] => @array";
        return \@array;
    } else {
        return $r;
    }
}

my @ranges = $range->rangeList;
foreach my $r (@ranges) {
    my @array = expand($r);
    #say STDERR Dumper(@array);
}
```